# Nil cannot initialize specified type 'UILabel'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm  a   newer  on IOS,  i  learn  from  the  others  project,  when  I import    others project ,Xcode  gives  some   compile   error  to  me , i  try   Google   but   it   didn't  give   some   useful   information, any   one   helps?

this is the code

```
@IBOutlet var ceshiLabel : UILabel? = nil
```

let  me   try  to  explain  the   question, i  want  to  declare a   UILable  in  the   swift,it  didn't   work  ,anyone  helps?

Comment: Hello, you are going to have to give us some more details on the error you are receiving. There are a couple of funky things going on with that single line of code but we can't help you if you don't give us more details.

Comment: I think all `@IBOutlet` must be connected to an object in Interface Builder. Xcode will give you a warning for unconnected `IBOutlet` so it cannot be `nil`

Comment: Hello You can implement like this                                                     @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

Answer (score -1):

You can declare `UILabel` with its property like its frame, label, name, textalignment, etc.

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))

label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)

label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

label.text = "I'am a test label"

self.view.addSubview(label)
```